# In Migrator.php line 418: Class 'Table' not found error on running a migration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to use [laravel-payment-gateway](https://github.com/nextpay-ir/laravel-payment-gateway) laravel package in my project.

It has two migration file that I added those to migration folder in laravel project. included :

**create_gateway_transactions_table.php**

```
namespace NextpayPayment\Gateway;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use NextpayPayment\Gateway\ConstGateway;

class CreateGatewayTransactionsTables extends Migration
{
    function getTable()
    {
        return config('gateway.table', 'nextpay_gateway_transactions');
    }

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->getTable(), function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = "innoDB";
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id', true);
            $table->enum('gateway', [
                ConstGateway::NEXTPAY,
            ]);
            $table->integer('status')->default(ConstGateway::TRANSACTION_PENDING);
            $table->integer('state')->default(ConstGateway::TRANSACTION_PENDING);
            $table->decimal('price', 15, 2);
            $table->string('trans_id', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('card_number', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('ip', 20)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('payment_date')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_commodity');
            $table->nullableTimestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop($this->getTable());
    }
}
```

And a **alter_id_in_transactions_table.php** like this :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AlterIdInTransactionsTables extends Migration
{

    function getTable()
    {
        return config('gateway.table', 'nextpay_gateway_transactions');
    }

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        try {       
//          DB::statement("update `" . $this->getTable() . "` set `payment_date`=null WHERE  `payment_date`=0;");
//          DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `" . $this->getTable() . "` CHANGE `id` `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL;");


            Schema::create('nextpay_gateway_transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->string('airline');
                $table->timestamps();
            });

        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
//      DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `" . $this->getTable() . "` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL;");
        Schema::drop($this->getTable());
    }
}
```

But after run `php artisan migrate` I got this error :

```
In Migrator.php line 418:

  Class 'Table' not found
```

What is problem and how can solve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating the migrations manually by running the following commands in the terminal/cmd:

```
php artisan make:migration create_gateway_transactions_tables
php artisan make:migration alter_id_in_transactions_table
```

Afterwards copy paste the code into the newly created migrations. Also try running:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

The migration file names must be the same as the class name. Also, you need to add date and time to the names. So, change file names to something like:

```
2018_01_15_100000_create_gateway_transactions_tables.php
2018_01_15_100001_alter_id_in_transactions_tables.php
```

Make sure other migrations are ok too and run `composer du`. Then use the migrations.

You can test this by yourself in Tinker:

```
$file = '2018_01_15_100000_create_gateway_transactions_tables.php';
$class = \Illuminate\Support\Str::studly(implode('_', array_slice(explode('_', $file), 4)));
```

The second line is from the method that gives you the error.